# Spark DataFrame Filtering Optimisation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, optimization, filter

I have a spark DF which has N different type of events. There are certain columns which help me in segregating the data in different buckets. Is there any way I can efficiently segregate / bucketise the data in smaller dataframes based on those columns ?

If there are 20 different kinds of events, then currently I am running the `.filter` operation in a loop 20 times. This is certainly like iterating over dataframe 20 times, and I feel this is totally redundant.

Is there any way in spark by which I can create the smaller and bucketed dataframes in a single iteration ? I have a feeling that a UDF might help here, but not sure how.

Any help would be appreciate. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, here are optimization strategies for filtering DataFrames in Apache Spark without providing specific code:

**Predicate Pushdown:**

Leverage predicate pushdown to minimize the amount of data read from storage. Filtering at the source, such as Parquet or ORC files, reduces the volume of data transferred to Spark.
**Partition Pruning:**

Ensure proper data partitioning. Filtering on partitioned columns allows Spark to skip reading entire partitions, reducing the data processed.

**Broadcast Join:**

Use broadcast joins when filtering involves a small DataFrame. This minimizes data shuffling during join operations.
Caching:

Cache frequently used DataFrames or portions of DataFrames to avoid recomputation and improve performance.
**Filter Pushdown to Data Source**:

When working with external data sources, make sure that filter conditions are pushed down to the source during Spark SQL queries.
**Avoid Using UDFs:**

Minimize the use of User-Defined Functions (UDFs) for filtering. Spark's built-in functions are optimized and can be more efficient.
**Optimize Storage Format:**

Choose a storage format like Parquet or ORC, which are columnar formats. They allow Spark to read only the necessary columns during filtering.
**Increase Parallelism:**

Adjust the level of parallelism for your Spark job by tuning the spark.sql.shuffle.partitions configuration. This controls the number of partitions used in shuffle operations.
**Use Filter Pushdown in Spark SQL:**

If using Spark SQL, write filters in SQL to take advantage of the Catalyst optimizer's filter pushdown capabilities.
**Avoid Costly Operations:**

Minimize the use of resource-intensive operations like sorting or repartitioning before filtering.
By incorporating these strategies, you can enhance the efficiency of your Spark DataFrame filtering operations, resulting in better performance for your Spark applications.

Comment: some of the above optimisations are not applicable for my use case. i need to read all the data as i need to bucketise all the data and push that to respective tables. I am already using parquet format. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).